# Trying to upload a blob image to Azure system with SAS Token, and get an Authentication error

Tags: php, azure, authentication, blob, azure-storage

I am using a PHP System to access to blob system and upload some image with SAS token. I can upload images correctly without SAS token, public, but private token I receive this error:

> InvalidAuthenticationInfoAuthentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header. RequestId: [xxx]**

I share with you my PHP code to do this. First, I have a PHP file where two functions are included for uploading:

```
function getAccessKey(){
    return strval("xxx");
}

function getSASForBlob($accountName,$container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry) {
    $key = getAccessKey();
    
    /* Create the signature */
    $_arraysign = array();
    $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
    $_arraysign[] = '/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = "2014-02-14"; //the API version is now required
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';

    $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);

    return base64_encode(
        hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($key), true)
    );
}

function uploadBlob($filepath, $storageAccountname, $containerName, $blobName, $_signature) {

    $accesskey = getAccessKey();
    $extUsed = explode(".",$filepath)[3];
    //$filepath = $filepath.'.'.$extUsed;
    $Date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
    $handle = fopen($filepath, "r");
    $fileLen = filesize($filepath);
    $blobName = $blobName.".".$extUsed;
    $URL = "https://$storageAccountname.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";
    
    $expiry = '';
    $resourceType = 'b';
    $permissions = 'r';
    
    $_parts = array();
    $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry))?'se=' . urlencode($expiry):'';
    $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
    $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions))?'sp=' . $permissions:'';
    $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
    $_parts[] = 'sv=2014-02-14';
    
    $URL = $URL . "?" . implode('&', $_parts);

     $headerResource = "x-ms-blob-cache-control:max-age=3600\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$Date\nx-ms-version:2017-11-09";
    $urlResource = "/$storageAccountname/$containerName/$blobName";
    $extUsed_folded = 'image/'.$extUsed;

    $arraysign = array();
    $arraysign[] = 'PUT';               /*HTTP Verb*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Encoding*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Language*/  
    $arraysign[] = $fileLen;            /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-MD5*/  
    $arraysign[] = $extUsed_folded          /*'application/pdf'*/;   /*Content-Type*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Date*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Modified-Since */  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Match*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-None-Match*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
    $arraysign[] = '';                  /*Range*/  
    $arraysign[] = $headerResource;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
    $arraysign[] = $urlResource;        /*CanonicalizedResource*/

    $str2sign = implode("\n", $arraysign);
    
      $sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($str2sign)), base64_decode($accesskey), true));  
  //  $sig = signWithAccountKey($str2sign, getAccessKey());
    $authHeader = "SharedKey $storageAccountname:$sig";

    $header_contentType = "image/".$extUsed;
    switch($extUsed){
        case "jpg": case "jpeg": default: break;
        case "png":
            $header_contentType = "image/png"; break;
        case "tiff":
            $header_contentType = "image/tiff"; break;
    }
    
    $headers = [
        'Authorization: ' . $authHeader,
        'x-ms-blob-cache-control: max-age=3600',
        'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob',
        'x-ms-date: ' . $Date,
        'x-ms-version: 2017-11-09',
        'Content-Type: '.$header_contentType,
        'Content-Length: ' . $fileLen
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileLen); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);



   // echo ('Uploaded successfully<br/>');
   // print_r($result);

    curl_close($ch);
    
    $resultsList = array( $URL , $filepath , $result , $blobName, $urlResource , $accesskey );
    
    if (isset($resultsList) && is_array($resultsList)) {
        return $resultsList;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
  
}
```

And after call this with an include into a my main PHP code, I do this:

```
$blobName = 'image-viajes';
$urlAdjunto = '';
$newFilename = '../Imagenes/temp_viajes.jpg';

if (!empty($filename)){
    
    $blobSignature = getSASForBlob('xxx', 'yyy', $blobName,
    'b', 'r', '');
    
    echo '<br /><b>BLOB SIGNATURE</b><p>'.$blobSignature.'</p>';
    
    //$blobFotoAdjunta__url = '';
    $blobFotoAdjunta = uploadBlob(
        $newFilename,
        'xxx', 'yyy',
        $blobName, $blobSignature);

}
```

I tried to quit parts addition to url into UploadBlob function, and it is uploaded correctly to server, but without token. In the moment I add GET variables into URL, I give this error. I generated this in Azure panel, for the container I selected.

I modified some data with XXX, yyy, etc. but I can say variables for public are correct. Problem is with Token. If you could see some problem in it, I would thank you too much.

Any question, I am. I don't know If I explained myself correctly as I must.

To upload an image to Azure server with private SAS token, and it doesn't works correctly. Public uploading is correct.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. You are creating SAS token but then creating the authorization header to upload the blob. You should use either one of them. If you are using SAS token, then simply create a SAS URL of the blob and make an HTTP PUT request to upload the blob. No need to use Put Blob REST API in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to upload a blob image to the Azure system with SAS Token

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment. You need to use either one of them and you can create an SAS token using the **`Azure Storage SDK for PHP`**.

In my environment, I first cloned the repository using the command below:

```php
git clone https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-php.git
```

Next, I installed all dependencies using `composer install` and created a PHP file named **`sample.php`** in the root directory.

**Code:**

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Autoload dependencies
require_once 'src/Blob/BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper.php';

use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper;

// Replace these values with your Azure Storage account details
$accountName = 'venkat789';
$accountKey = '<Your-account-key>';
$containerName = 'sample';
$blobName = 'sample.png';

// Create BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper instance
$blobSasHelper = new BlobSharedAccessSignatureHelper($accountName, $accountKey);

// Generate a shared access signature for the blob
$signedResource = 'b'; // Blob resource type
$resourceName = $containerName . '/' . $blobName;
$signedPermissions = 'rw'; // Read permission
$signedExpiry = new DateTime('2024-04-01T00:00:00Z');

$sasToken = $blobSasHelper->generateBlobServiceSharedAccessSignatureToken(
    $signedResource,
    $resourceName,
    $signedPermissions,
    $signedExpiry,
);

// Construct the full URI with the generated SAS token
$blobUriWithSas = "https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName?$sasToken";

// Replace with the path to the file you want to upload
$filePath = 'C:\zzzzz\mountainview.png';

// Use cURL to upload the blob with SAS token
$handle = fopen($filePath, 'r');
$fileLen = filesize($filePath);

$headers = [
    'Content-Length: ' . $fileLen,
    'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob',
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $blobUriWithSas);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);  // Enable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileLen);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 300) {
        echo 'Upload successful.' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'Upload failed. HTTP Code: ' . $httpCode . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Response: ' . $result . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

The above script uploads a file to Azure Blob Storage using a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token. It generates a SAS token with read and write permissions that expires on April 1, 2024. The script constructs the full URI for the blob with the SAS token and uses cURL to upload the file to the blob. Finally, it outputs a message indicating whether the upload was successful or not.

**Output:**

```
Upload successful.
```

[image]

**Portal**

[image]